# how to clean old log from logcat, the logcat -c doesn't work

Tags: android, logcat

from cmd:
C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb shell

and then logcat -b radio

it prints old historic log. I tried to call logcat -c like this:
1. adb shell
2. logcat -c and it returns no error
3. exit and reenter adb shell
4. logcat -b radio(I got the same with or without step 3)

and it didn't work it always got the old log as well. Any idea what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: HEllo. What do you mean by "old log"? -b only switches buffers to put the log into.

Answer (score 1):

"logcat -b radio -c",to chean the old radio log,and  then "logcat -b radio".